# Remove a data connection from an Excel 2010 spreadsheet in compatibility mode

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Situation: an Excel 2010 workbook is created using data from oracle.  A data connection is created to achieve this.  The excel workbook is then saved as a .xls file so that customers with older versions of office can access it.

Problem: a warning message is displayed when the workbook is opened:

'Security warning       Data Connections have been disabled           [ Enable content]'.

We think this is shown because the data connection is still present in the workbook.  You can go to Data->Connections and remove it, but when the workbook is saved and re-opened, the data connection has come back (although with empty definitions fields).

Things tried: removing all data connections using a macro: no joy.  The 'Name Manager' method described here (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=467938) : no joy.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Comment: Note - saving as 2010 xlsx format then removing the connection works, but when that same workbook is re-saved as .xls format, the connection comes back again. Gah!

Comment: We have also tried the method of saving as xlsx, opening the file as a compressed archive, directly editing xl/connections.xml and then re-saving, but this breaks any pivot tables in the workbook! It looks like pivot tables will only work if there is a data connection - the best you can do is just to blank the DSN and SQL fields.

Comment: What do you do to "remove it"? I don't find a remove button anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, Soren, I'm afraid this is a long time in the past for me now, but hopefully someone else can assist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem today.  If after you delete all of the connections, the connection properties still live on.  I clicked on properties, deleted the name by selecting the name window and deleting it.

A warning came up to verify I really wanted to do it.  After selecting yes, it got rid of the connection.  Save the workbook.

I am a hack at Excel but this seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks Dave - can't remember what we actually did to resolve this in the end but more than likely we let it drop unsolved.

Comment: It appears there is also a bug in Excel where deleting the connection does not fully disassociate the refresh settings, so when next time the file tries to refresh, the connection is missing resulting in an empty table. To resolve this, I went to the Data -> Connections -> [connection] -> Properties... **BEFORE** deleting the connection and disabled all refresh settings. I think this may be specific though to the "Remove data from the external data range before saving the workbook" setting.

Answer (score 9):

Select a cell in the cell range in which the data is imported, then Menu > Data > Properties > uncheck save query definition.

Properties will be greyed out unless a cell in the data import range is selected.

You can find out the range in which the data isimported by:

Menu > Data > Connections > (select connection) > Click here to see where the selected connections are used.

Answer (score 4):

When the ***Import Data*** box pops up
click on **Properties** and remove the
*Check Mark* next to **Save query definition** 
When the ***Import Data*** box comes back
and your location is where you want it to be
(Ex: =$I$4) click on **OK** and your problem
will be resolved

Answer (score 3):

I manage to solve this in excel 97-2003, in a file with .xls extension this way:
I went to the page where I had the linked data, with the cursor over the imported data table, go to tab Design --> External Data Table --> Unlink
Unlink all tables (conections), delete all conections in Data --> Conections --> Conections
save your work and done!
regards,
Dan

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Get the warning. Went to Data connections and deleted connection. Save, close reopen. Still get the warning.
I use a xp/vista menu plugin for classic menus. I found under data, get external data, properties, uncheck the save query definition. Save close and reopen. 
That seemed to get rid of the warning.
Just removing the connection does not work. You have to get rid of the query.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced that a drop-down menu, referring to a control range (for example after copying sheets from one workbook to another), will keep that cell reference after copying the worksheet, and keeps a data connection which is invisible in "Connections". I found this in the "Search" menu in the ribbon, where an arrow can be selected to mark objects. Underneath the arrow is a menu selection to see all the objects listed in a panel. Then you can delete those unwanted objects and the data source/connection is gone...

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2010: On the File/Info page, go to 'Related Documents' and click break links => warning will appear that all linked values will be converted to their data values => click ok => done

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Please try this:

```vb
Sub deleteConn(xlBook)
    For Each Cn In xlBook.Connections
        Cn.Delete
    Next Cn

    For Each xlsheet In xlBook.Worksheets
        For Each Qt In xlsheet.QueryTables
            Qt.Delete
        Next Qt
    Next xlsheet

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

That is okay for removing of data connections by using VBA as follows:

```
Sub deleteConn()
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim Cn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Qt As QueryTable
    Set xlBook = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each Cn In xlBook.Connections
        Debug.Print VarType(Cn)
        Cn.Delete
    Next Cn
    For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets
        For Each Qt In xlSheet.QueryTables
            Debug.Print Qt.Name
            Qt.Delete
        Next Qt
    Next xlSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: please add a brief explanation to your answer

Comment: I tried to manually remove all connections in the excel file, but not work. Finally, I just followed Dang Thanh's VBA statement and rectified it which successfully removed connections. In first loop, delete all connections which connects external file. In second loop, delete all QueryTables. Remember **to save** your excel file after running it.

Answer (score 1):

I had many connections I couldn't delete but didn't want to delete them all. So, I extended Dang Thanh and Richard Ho 's solution so it would prompt user to decide which connections to delete.

To delete some but not all connections in a Workbook:

```
Public Function deleteConnections()

    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim Result As Variant

    Set xlBook = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each cn In xlBook.Connections

        Dim strMsg As String
        strMsg = "Would you like to delete: " & vbNewLine & cn.Name
        Result = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo)

        If Result = vbYes Then
            cn.Delete
        End If

    Next cn

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The data imported through external connections is imported into a table. To unlink the table from data, please:

1. Click on any cell in the table with imported data.
2. Click "Table Design" on menu.
3. In the toolbar group "External Table Data", click "Unlink". Click OK on the confirmation prompt.

This should unlink the table and remove any connection related information from the Excel file.

In VBA, you can use the below command:

```
<sheetname>.ListObjects("<table name>").Unlink
```

please replace `<sheetname>` with the name of the sheet and `<tabe name>` with the name of the table that is linked to external data.